# CodeIgniter autoload a package

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to instantiate a class every time a page is loaded in CodeIgniter.

It looks like the /application/config/autoload.php is the place to do this. Is that correct?

I added this line to the package's autoload:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array('/application/third_party/Autoload.php');
```

Now I need this code to be executed on every page, where can I make this happen?

```
$bugsnag = new Bugsnag_Client("YOUR-API-KEY-HERE");
set_error_handler(array($bugsnag, "errorHandler"));
set_exception_handler(array($bugsnag, "exceptionHandler"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let me explain it how you can do  it.
As you have autoloaded the package its fine now you need to do this.
Create a MY_Controller in application/core/ directory.

```
Class MY_Controller Extends CI_Controller{

    public $bugsnag =   '';
    public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
        $this->bugsnag = new Bugsnag_Client("YOUR-API-KEY-HERE");
        set_error_handler(array($bugsnag, "errorHandler"));
        set_exception_handler(array($bugsnag, "exceptionHandler"));     
    }
}
```

Note `$this->bugsnag` contains the object now. When you need to access it in any page you can simply do it like this by extending the parent class

```
Class Test Extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_R($this->bugsnag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To auto load a package (according to `CI`), you should put the `package path/name` in following array, like

```
$autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'third_party', '/usr/local/shared');
```

But it doesn't execute any code automatically but makes your package available to use without explicitly loading it.

To make some code execute every time, you can put that code in your base controller's `constructor` function. Also, you can put the code in your `config.php` file. If you have an extended base controller, like `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    //
}
```

Then you can use it's constructor function like

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->bugsnag = new Bugsnag_Client("YOUR-API-KEY-HERE");
            set_error_handler(array($bugsnag, "errorHandler"));
            set_exception_handler(array($bugsnag, "exceptionHandler"));
}
}
```

Rest of your controllers will use/extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`.

But you can also use a `hook` in this case (to register custom exception handlers), in `application/config/hooks.php` file, put following code

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'CustomExceptionHook',
    'function' => 'SetExceptionHandlers',
    'filename' => 'CustomExceptionHook.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Create a class in `application/hooks/CustomExceptionHook.php` folder, like

```
class CustomExceptionHook
{
    public function SetExceptionHandlers()
    {
        // add package path (if not auto-loaded)
        $this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/package_folder/');
        // load package (if not auto-loaded)
        $this->load->library('Bugsnag_Client');

        set_error_handler(array($this->Bugsnag_Client, "errorHandler"));
        set_exception_handler(array($this->Bugsnag_Client, "exceptionHandler"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of MY_Controller.php
This is using BugSnag via composer install

Using this method exposes the `$this->_bugsnag` variable to the entire CI System

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    // Application Version
    public $_app_version;

    // Bugsnag
    public $_bugsnag = NULL;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        // Dont print errors to screen
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);

        // Load configs
        $this->load->config('appversion');
        $this->load->config('bugsnag');
        $this->_app_version = $this->config->item('app_version');

        // INIT: bugsnag
        // https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/other/configuration-options/
        $this->_bugsnag = Bugsnag\Client::make( $this->config->item('bugsnagAPIKey') );
        $this->_bugsnag->setErrorReportingLevel( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED );
        $this->_bugsnag->setNotifyReleaseStages( ['developement', 'testing', 'production'] );
        $this->_bugsnag->setReleaseStage( ENVIRONMENT );
        $this->_bugsnag->setAppType( 'API Server' );
        $this->_bugsnag->setAppVersion( $this->_app_version );
        $this->_bugsnag->setHostname( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
        $this->_bugsnag->setProjectRoot( realpath(APPPATH) );
        $this->_bugsnag->setFilters( ['password'] );
        Bugsnag\Handler::register( $this->_bugsnag );

        // Load Helpers

        // Load Libraries

        // Load Languages
    }
}
```

You can now access the BugSnag methods like this.

```
$this->_bugsnag->leaveBreadcrumb( 'Hello' );
$this->_bugsnag->notifyException( $e );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a MY_Controller & inherit all your controllers off that. You can find more on this by Googling "MY_Controller"